# How to remove all scrolling and click events when displaying Overlay in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlay

I have an Overlay that I display on a webpage while some SQL is performed in the background, this SQL can take a good few seconds, so I set this Overlay to be on the screen for 10 seconds using JavaScript.  What I want to do, is prevent the user from clicking, and scrolling altogether while this Overlay is visible.

I have the pointer events set to 'none' which doesn't seem to work, even with a high z-index, and displaying as 'block'.  For some reason, when the Overlay is displayed, the user can still scroll, click, and highlight text just like the overlay is not even there.

This is my Overlay in CSS:

```
    #overlay {

        position:fixed;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.9);
        pointer-events: none;
        z-index:100000;
      
    }
```

My JavaScript:

```
  //The function to start displaying the overlay

    function start()
    {   
     document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";        
    }


    //The function to stop displaying the overlay
    function end()
    {
            alert("Finished!");
            document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
    }

 

    setTimeout(function() { start(); }, 1);  //starting the Overlay
    setTimeout(function() { end(); }, 10000); //ending the Overlay after 10 seconds
```

Comment: just include `position: fixed;` in the overlay css

Comment: I've added it in and it hasn't made any difference unfortunately

Comment: A full implementation of a "modal" pop-up in JS is extremely complex. If you're satisfied with preventing mouse events only, you can include `pointer-events: none` to the CSS for `#overlay`. But, that doesn't prevent keyboard navigation on the page, nor it pauses the possible timers etc. But it looks like you've already added the property, I'd assume the overlay element is not on the top of the position stack, place the element as the last element just before the closing `body` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `pointer-events: none` to allow the user to click on the overlay, and add `user-select:none;` instead.

This way, the user can not select anything on the overlay. The user will only be able to resume selection on the other parts of the page once the overlay is hidden.

```js
function start() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}


//The function to stop displaying the overlay
function end() {
  
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
  console.log('Finished');
}



setTimeout(function() {
  start();
}, 1); //starting the Overlay

setTimeout(function() {
  end();
}, 10000); //ending the Overlay after 10 seconds
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.9);
  z-index: 100000;
  user-select: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* not really needed, but this prevents scroll bars from appearing */
}

#main {
  background-color: #bada55;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5em;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
  <p>
    This is part of the overlay inner HTML
  </p>
</div>

<div id="main">
  This is something not inside the overlay
</div>
```

Comment: I've used [this](https://jsfiddle.net/25z7mof6/) in my own projects, can you explain why the overlay doesn't work in the linked fiddle? (The CSS works fine in my projects, though.)

Comment: You forgot to remove `pointer-events: none;` from the css. I have removed it in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ka1tLr7w/ and it worked as expected.

Comment: Umm ... Actually I added `user-select: none;` to the CSS, like I said, it works perfectly in projects (just checked a couple of pages), but doesn't seem to work in the fiddle. But like you said, it works in the fiddle without `pointer-events`. This becomes at least a bit weird now ...

Answer (score 0):

You should disable scrolling by add `overflow: hidden` to `body`

```
function start()
{   
   document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";        
   document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow = "hidden";        
}


//The function to stop displaying the overlay
function end()
{
   alert("Finished!");
   document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow = null;        
}
```